# Add new attribute dynamically to the existing model object in Yii2 framework

Tags: yii2

In Yii2 framework is it possible to add a new attribute dynamically to an existing object, which is retrieved from Database?

Example

```
//Retrieve from $result
$result = Result::findone(1);
//Add dynamic attribute to the object say 'result'
$result->attributes = array('attempt' => 1);
```

If it is not possible, please suggest an alternate best method to implement it.

Finally I would be converting the result to a json object. In my application, at the behaviour code block, I have used like this:

```
'formats' => [
               'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,  
             ],
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add define a public variable inside your model, that will store dynamic attributes as associative array. It'll look something like this:

```
class Result extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements Arrayable
{
    public $dynamic;

    // Implementation of Arrayable fields() method, for JSON
    public function fields()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'id',
            'created_at' => 'created_at',
            // other attributes...
            'dynamic' => 'dynamic',
        ];
    }
    ...
```

..in your action pass some dynamic values to your model, and return everything as JSON:

```
public function actionJson()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    $model = Result::findOne(1);
    $model->dynamic = [
        'field1' => 'value1',
        'field2' => 2,
        'field3' => 3.33,
    ];

    return $model;
}
```

In result you will get JSON like this:

```
{"id":1,"created_at":1499497557,"dynamic":{"field1":"value1","field2":2,"field3":3.33}}
```

Comment: It is working. Is it possible to do without declaring fields function in model class.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible if you use ActiveRecord.